# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sendMessage')

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make the selected text change into the p element of id 'ext' in popup.html and popup.js when I click the buy button but I seem to get undefined.

This is my manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "hoko's ext",
    "description": "my ext",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html" 
      },
      "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
      ],
      "background": {
        "service-worker": "background.js"
      },
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["https://*/*"],
          "js": ["content.js"]
        }
      ]
  
}
```

This is my popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>I am the popup</h1>

<button id="btn">Buy</button>
<p id="ext">Hello</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my background.js service worker

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(receiver);
window.word = 'Hello';
function receiver(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.text === 'Hello') {
    sendResponse(request);
}}
```

This is my content script.
The error is at content.js:13 (anonymous function)

```
console.log('yo');
window.addEventListener('mouseup', word);

function word() {
    console.log('word selected');
    let select = window.getSelection().toString();
    console.log(select);

    if (select.length > 0) {
        let message = {
            text: select
        };
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message);
    }
}
```

And lastly this is my popup.js script

```
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({text: "Hello"}, function(response) {
        document.getElementById('ext').innerHTML = response;
    
    }
    ); 
    })
```

Comment: You probably opened popup.html as a file:// or http:// page. It's wrong. Click the extension's icon in the browser toolbar to open the popup. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I just had to replace - with _ in service-worker in manifest.json and everything worked perfectly! I edited my code however in background.js, content.js and popup.js.

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "hoko's ext",
    "description": "my ext",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html" 
      },
      "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
      ],
      "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
      },
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["https://*/*"],
          "js": ["content.js"]
        }
      ]
  
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Your backgroundScript receiver isn't doing anything when it gets the message (selected word) from the contentScript.

```
//backgroundScript.js

var selectedWord;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
   function(request,sender,sendResponse){
      if(request.text === 'Hello'){
         //send saveWord variable to popup
         sendResponse({word:selectedWord});
      } else {
         //save request.text
         selectedWord = request.text
      }
      return true; //for async reasons i dont get either
   }
);

//popupScript.js

... document.getElementById('ext').innerHTML = response.word;
```

I hope this helps?

Comment: I tried this and the 'ext' just stayed the same. I switched up my code a bit and now it is saying Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.